# Form submit Ajax using jQuery sometimes does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am doing form data submit using Ajax with jQuery.
When I submit form on popup window, I refresh the parent page.
My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#frm_addSpeedData").submit(function(event) {  
    //event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
          url: "/webapp/addSpeedDataAction.do", 
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            //console.log("Data: " + data);
            window.opener.location.reload(); 
          }
        });
    });
});
```

However page gets refreshed on success of callback but i can not see update on my parent page. Sometimes I can see updates and sometimes not. What is the issue? I also need to know how I can write it in native javascript and submit form using ajax javascript.

Comment: Did you use firebug to debug the ajax method calls are returning 200 OK ?

Comment: Yes. returning 200 ok I can see

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your getting this error due the fact that javascript is async and your code will proceed even when you have yet no response from the request.

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#frm_addSpeedData").submit(function(event) {  
        //event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST", 
              url: "/webfdms/addSpeedDataAction.do", 
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              async: false, // This will only proceed after getting the response from the ajax request.
              success: function(data) {
                //console.log("Data: " + data);
                window.opener.location.reload(); 
              }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: But i can see the page getting refreshed. That means ajax call has been successful. Is it or not ?

Comment: The problem is: Imagine that you have a validation where if field "X" is an unique value in the database. When you run AJAX to validate this you have to get data from the database and then validate if it is unique or not. If the request takes to long it might proceed to the submit without validating the field. Let me know if I'm not being clear. In this example I cannot replicate the bug so makes harder for me.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: uncomment this part event.preventDefault();  you have to prevent the default behavior of the submit function, otherwise there's no fun in using ajax .

Comment: @psylogic what it does ?

Comment: you have to prevent the default behavior of the submit function, otherwise there's no fun in using ajax

Comment: it stops the default submit behavior and let's you use ajax instead!

Comment: will it post my data to server if I do so or not ?

Comment: @Wilson- I got your clarification.

Comment: Actually it doesn't mean that the ajax call has been successful or not. Javascript will just read all of your code in 1 way. From the top to the bottom, and will ignore your ajax request. But to debug better I would change the reload to: window.location.href = 'www.google.com' or something. Maybe the reload you're getting isn't the ajax response load . Maybe you are getting redirected to the link in form attribute 'action'.

Comment: yes off course it would, you see if you dont prevent the default behavior of the submit it'll refresh your popup

Comment: @psylogic what I need to do so that this code will work properly everytime ?

Comment: first thing like I told you yesterday don't use a submit button use a normal button instead so that it doesn't hinder with the ajax call.

Comment: bhai but its control is not with me. I can not change it to normal button

Comment: Aint a cache problem? Try to debug using the window.location I've recommended few responses ago. this way you'll find out when you get redirected from the ajax response and when not.

Comment: @Wilson- window.location redirects you to another page! he wants to refresh the existing parent page that's why he's using window.opener.location.reload();

Comment: I know right but all I'm asking is for debug... I'm not even considering this as solution to the problem. I just want to know if it is an async problem.

Comment: uncomment the event.preventDefault(); and see if the data is posted to the server or not!

Comment: @psylogic by uncommenting the event.preventDefault() it does not post data to server

Comment: mahendra I want to help you with this problem. Can you chat me here in stack? Actually I don't know if I can already chat here

Comment: so that's the problem! you need to fix your ajax request first. get it working and only after a successful response would the window.opener.location.reload();  work

Comment: Im saying that for like an hour now... Just debug the way I said. If you get redirected to the google page then your AJAX is ok. If you get redirected to the same page then your AJAX is wrong. Easy debug for detecting the real problem....

Comment: @Wilson yes it is redirecting me to same page.

Comment: @psylogic my form tag also does have action="/addSpeedDataAction". Is that causing a problem ?

Comment: so with this debug you findout that the reload isn't from the ajax response but from the action url.

Comment: @Wilson- yes, it is form action url.

Comment: @Wilson- I can not initiate chat

Comment: Try once again the async: false, but reload it with CTRL + F5 sometimes in order to clear the javascript cache from the browser. After doing that check the source code of the page to see if the async: false configuration is already in your js source code and then execute the code. After executing check the developer tool in order to see if there is any type of error. Also check the XHR request in your browser. Let me know if you didn't understand

Comment: @Wilson- my form tag looks like this: <html:form styleId="frm_addSpeedData" action="/addSpeedDataAction" name="addSpeedData" type="fdms.ui.struts.form.AddSpeedDataForm">

Comment: do you have skype? or give me your gmail email to hangout you.

Comment: I mean to say URL i am using to make ajax call is = http://localhost:8080/webfdms/addSpeedDataAction.do and my form tag also has action="/addSpeedDataAction" . does that causes a problem ?

Comment: you dont need action attribute as you are posting the value through ajax

Comment: Please avoid using extensive comments. Use the chat instead

Comment: @psylogic if i remove action attribute then it gives me error.

Comment: @Lucky since the person I am dealing with does not have enough reputations, we need to talk in comments.

Comment: action="#" should do it!